# Extract Link and Title Within a Heading Tag with bs4

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have used the below code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get(
    "https://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/entertain/best-ever-starter-recipes/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


for i in soup.find_all('h3')[1:-3]:
    print(i)
```

To get this kind of output:

```
<h3 class="p1"><a href="https://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/meat-and-poultry/summer-deli-board/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Summer deli board</a></h3>
<h3 class="p1"><a href="https://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/entertain/marinated-figs-with-mozzarella-and-serrano-ham/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Marinated figs with mozzarella and serrano ham</a></h3>
<h3><a href="http://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/meat-and-poultry/tomato-salad-with-burrata-and-warm-nduja-dressing/">Tomato salad with burrata and warm 'nduja dressing</a></h3>
<h3 class="p1"><a href="https://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/quick-and-easy/griddled-avocados-with-crab-and-chorizo/" rel="noopener" target="_blank">Griddled avocados with crab and chorizo</a></h3>
<h3><a href="http://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/meat-and-poultry/duck-chicken-and-sour-cherry-terrine/">Duck, chicken and sour cherry terrine</a></h3>
<h3><a href="http://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/steak-tartare/3000.html" target="_self">Steak tartare</a></h3>
<h3><a href="http://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/meat-and-poultry/tomatoes-and-lardo-on-toast-with-basil-oil/">Tomatoes and lardo on toast with basil oil</a></h3>
```

From here I would like to extract the link in the anchor tag as well as the display name eg Summer Deli board.

I am not sure how to extract these two elements from where I have gotten so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a nested loop inside you for loop to get `href` and text for your code and `append` into the `list`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get(
    "https://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/entertain/best-ever-starter-recipes/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

link=[]
title=[]
for i in soup.find_all('h3')[1:-3]:
    a_tag=i.find_all("a")
    
    for i in a_tag:
        link.append(i.attrs['href'])
        title.append(i.text)
```

Output:

```
 link:

['https://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/family/giant-champagne-and-lemon-prawn-vol-au-vents/',
 'https://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/fish-and-seafood/grilled-scallops-with-nduja-butter/',
 'https://www.olivemagazine.com/recipes/quick-and-easy/herb-and-chilli-calamari/',.......]

title:
['Giant champagne and lemon prawn vol-au-vents',
 'Grilled scallops with ’nduja butter',
 'Herb and chilli calamari',....]
```